# Which cloud server provider is best for accepting bitcoin payments with BTCPay Server?

Tags: server, payment-processors, merchants, ecommerce

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00YCc87RwnU) shows someone using lunanode for their BTCPayServer cloud server. What are the other top reputable and reliable cloud servers out there for running an online store that wants to act as its own payment processor via BTCPay?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's my video :D

Lunanode provides easy "1 click install" process. You can host btcpay server on any other VPS server (like azure, aws, digitalocean etc.) but the process will be just a bit more complicated, and will require downloading and configuring btcpayserver.

As always any solution will have some tradeoffs, like cost or how easy it is to use, how reputable is the provider, etc.

All methods of hosting are presented in [this document](https://docs.btcpayserver.org/Deployment/).

Comment: are you one of the developers behind btcpay server?

Comment: No, I am just an educator and content creator.

Comment: Can BtcPay Server be configured to receive payments at a .crypto or .eth domain address rather than the full-length wallet addresses?

Answer (score 0):

> Which cloud server provider is best for accepting bitcoin payments with BTCPay Server?

None

I would prefer deployment on a Raspberry Pi instead of cloud(someone else's computer) for something related to bitcoin : https://docs.btcpayserver.org/RPi4/

Reasons: Privacy, Security and you can buy one for less than $100. [Raspberry Pi 400](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-400/) is built into a compact keyboard